# Database design price changes for every day

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I got a table (tableA) with an auto current_timestamp column.
All entries will be counted and at the moment multiplied by a constant to get the price.
Lets say the count is 1000 and the constant is 2.00. That makes a price of 1000 * 2.00 = 2$

Now i want to change this constant whenever I need to.
I probably have to create a table (tableB) with the values

```
date         pricefactor
2014-09-01   0.002
2014-09-20   0.001
2014-10-01   0.003
```

When i request now the price for all of the entries in tableA i want to get the value by multiplying all entries times the pricefactor in tableB.

So i would maybe got a count of 100 till the 20th, 1000 till the 1st of october and 200 after the 1st of october.
That would make:

```
100  * 0.002 = 0.200$
1000 * 0.001 = 1.000$
200  * 0.003 = 0.600$
---------------------
       total = 1.800$
```

Is this thought ok till yet? or is there something i should change?

I just want to do it right so I ask for your opinion ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add one more column named count to table B. You can write a trigger for Table A. Whenever there is a change in table A (add or delete), increment/decrement the count in table B for the row containing the time-stamp. Finally multiply count*respective price from table B and aggregate everything.

Comment: I cant do it that way... We got many entries of many users in tableA thats why it has to be different.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea I would suggest is to create an api to retrieve live price.